# AndEngine animate sprites on parallax background help! :)

Tags: android, andengine, parallax, sprite, animated

[image: Example]

Hi, My name is Jonas and i am attending a university course in Android programming.
I always have to take the hard way and going AndEngine.

In the above picture you can see that i am using a Parallax background with three layers.
I am making a sidescroller so the bottom layer with the blue line that is an ice track is scrolling. I want to animate this picture and put it on the track.

[image: Picture i want to animate]

When i load it as i animate the two people in the backgroud that is animated in the same way the emulator is going apeshit and showing me a small triangle of the picture in the corner of the screen. A animated picture that works is this one:

[image: (Picture that works.)]

Is my animated picture of the horse to big or is it something else i am doing wrong. There is not much i find on the internet about this matter! I would really appreciate all the help i can get!

This is an example of my code and i know it is a ripoff of andEngine Examples but i am here to learn.

```
package com.example.towerofhanoi;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.AutoParallaxBackground;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import       org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObjectManager;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

/**
 * (c) 2010 Nicolas Gramlich
 *
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
 * @since 19:58:39 - 19.07.2010
 */
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;
private TiledTextureRegion mEnemyTextureRegion;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture;

private ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerBack;
private ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerMid;
private ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerFront;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "player.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);
    this.mEnemyTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "enemy.png", 73, 0, 3, 4);
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

    this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
    this.mParallaxLayerFront = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_front.png", 0, 0);
    this.mParallaxLayerBack = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_back.png", 0, 188);
    this.mParallaxLayerMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_mid.png", 0, 669);
    this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load();
}

@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    final AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);
    final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerBack.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerBack, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f, new Sprite(0, 80, this.mParallaxLayerMid, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerFront.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerFront, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
    scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);

    /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */
    final float playerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float playerY = CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight() - 5;

    /* Create two sprits and add it to the scene. */
    final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(playerX +230, playerY-180, this.mPlayerTextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    player.setScaleCenterY(this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight());
    player.setScale(2);
    player.animate(new long[]{100, 100, 100}, 6, 8, true);

    final AnimatedSprite enemy = new AnimatedSprite(playerX + 200, playerY -180, this.mEnemyTextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    enemy.setScaleCenterY(this.mEnemyTextureRegion.getHeight());
    enemy.setScale(2);
    enemy.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);

    scene.attachChild(player);
    scene.attachChild(enemy);

    return scene;
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
}
```

thanks in advance...

/Jonas

Comment: Are you using GLES 1 or GLES 2? Also, have you tried your app on an actual device? The emulator has a tendency of being silly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same textureatlas to generate both textures.  Here's your textureatlas definition:

```
this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
```

They Y dimension there (128) is too small for this image.  Instead, make a second texture atlas for the player image, with at least 256 height (it wants powers of 2) and it will cover it.

Also, I want to make sure you're doing this intentionally:

```
  this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "player.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);
```

Those last two numbers (3 and 4) represent the number of columns and rows of your horse spritesheet.  But when I look at your horse, I only see three by three, not three by four:

[image]

It might be you want that whitespace as three additional cells in the animation, but make sure you're doing that on purpose.  The createTiledFromAsset() method assumes the sprites are fitting within a grid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that solves it.  If you agree and want to award that green check mark, it'd be much appreciated. ;)