# How to attach animated sprites with AutoParallax Backgrounds in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have created game in AndEngine in which i used basically 2 things. Autoparallax background and animated sprites .

I am moving the background and animated sprites in -X direction .So I used " "mPhysicshandler.velocityX(minus)".Now the game is perfect .

But after playing sometimes the screen hangs maximum times. I test the game in samsung and also motorolla phones. i think the problem is animated sprites. As the backgroung is moving toward -X with 30 speed, i have to move all animated sprites towards -X with double of background speed . Otherwise the move of animated sprites are not showing clearly.

So now I want to fix the problem by attaching animated sprites with the parallax background. So i don't need to use velocities for each animated sprites.

But after attaching the sprites are moving with the background clearly but not animated.

I check something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828487/andengine-animate-sprites-on-parallax-background-help) ,but it didn't help me in my problem.

Please help .
Any type of suggestions are appreciated .

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backgoround is a type of an entity that is not redrawing...
That's why it's better to use background, not a sprite. Cause sprite will be redrawn 60 times per sec, but not a background